# How to prevent race condition when multiple threads are writing in the same file descriptor in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, printf, mutex

I have the following function that will run in the thread:

```
void    *dinning_handler(void *arg)
{
    t_philo         *philo;
    struct timeval  start;

    philo = (t_philo *)arg;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    philo->last_meal_time = start;
    while (philo->max_eats == -1 || philo->eats < philo->max_eats)
    {
        print_blue("is thinking", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
        pthread_mutex_lock(philo->left_fork);
        pthread_mutex_lock(philo->right_fork);
        print_blue("has taken a fork", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
        print_green("is eating", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
        usleep(philo->time_to_eat * 1000);
        philo->eats++;
        gettimeofday(&philo->last_meal_time, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(philo->left_fork);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(philo->right_fork);
        print_blue("is sleeping", philo->id, get_ts_in_ms());
        usleep(philo->time_to_sleep * 1000);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

each of the print functions will have the following format:

```
void    print_red(char **msg, int id, long time)
{
    ft_printf("\033[1;31m");
    ft_printf("%u %d %s\n", time, id, msg);
    ft_printf("\033[0m");
}
```

This generate a race condition leading to write wrong values in the terminal. If I replace ft_print(which is a self implementation that suppose to work the same way of printf) for the original printf it works fine. Why? do printf use mutex before print? how can I fix my code?

EDIT:

[Link](https://github.com/Vinny-Bass/42-course/tree/main/Ft_printf) for ft_printf implementation, it is too big to put it here

Comment: We'd need to see `ft_print` to say why its behavior differs from `printf`.

Comment: I have added the link with the implementation

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, `printf()` is required to be thread-safe, so it must use a mutex. Read the man page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I replace ft_print for the original printf it works fine. Why?

POSIX requires `printf` to be thread-safe.

But a sequence of `printf` statements is not atomic, so you also got lucky.

You need to ensure the group of `printf` calls are executed atomically. In this case, the best solution is to combine them into one.

```c
printf(
   "\033[1;31m"
   "%u %d %s\n"
   "\033[0m",
   time, id, msg
);
```

---

> how can I fix my code?

As with `printf`, you need to make the group of calls to `ft_printf` atomic. Yes, you could use a mutex to achieve this.

```
// Lock the mutex here.
ft_printf( "\033[1;31m" );
ft_printf( "%u %d %s\n", time, id, msg );
ft_printf( "\033[0m" );
// Unlock it here.
```

Comment: Note that just blindly putting a mutex into ft_printf won't help -- you need to determine what needs to be output atomically and ensure mulitple such do not get intermixed.

Comment: @Chris Dodd, Correct. It needs to be around the group of calls. It's needed for `printf` as well, as the answer already states. (Well, it was implied, but I just made it more explicit.)

Answer (score 2):

The real difference you're seeing from printf is coming from BUFFERING, not synchronization.

Printf (and stdio functions in general) all actually just write output into a buffer, and don't actually output anything until the buffer is flushed.  By default, that happens whenever a `\n` (newline) character is output, or when the buffer fills up.  So with your code, if you had:

```
printf("\033[1;31m");
printf("%u %d %s\n", time, id, msg);
```

the first line would just write to the buffer, and the second line would then be appended to the buffer, and then the whole line will be written as one call.  When using separate processes, this gives the effect of having things be atomic, as the underlying write call will write the line to the terminal as an atomic unit.

Note that just using a internal mutex and making each call to ft_printf atomic wouldn't help, as these two calls really need to be combined into an atomic unit.  Using a mutex in each print_*color* to make the whole call atomic would work.

Your existing code appears to use pthreads, so just using printf (with the shared STDOUT buffer, and a mutex lock in each printf call) might appear to work, but it will still see occasional failures if two threads try to write lines with different colors simultaneously.

Comment: Writing bytes to a buffer isn’t inherently atomic; printf() locks a mutex to ensure atomicity.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: yes, but that turns out to not be adequate (or very relevant) in this case.

Comment: Re "*This gives the effect of having this be atomic*", No it doesn't. Buffering is not relevant at all.